# Make an exception with a mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on a CMS with CodeIgniter and I would like to make an exception with my SQL query

```
function get_categories()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('ft_categories');
    return $query->result();
}
```

This function will get every categories in my TABLE and I want to remove something from this result

Example :

I get this : **CAT1 - CAT2 - CAT3 - SPECIALCAT** from the query and I would like to remove the SPECIALCAT from the result by the name of this CAT

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either:

```
$this->db->where('CAT !=', "SPECIALCAT");
$query = $this->db->get('ft_categories');
return $query->result();
```

or

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('ft_categories, 'CAT !=', "SPECIALCAT");
return $query->result();
```

These assume that your field name is "CAT" and the value of the category you want to avoid retrieving is "SPECIALCAT".  They're equivalent statements just slightly different formatting.  See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html for more info.

Comment: I feel stupid, that was easy as that :p That definitely makes sense now!